# Unpredictable system freeze, possibly related to "Daily apt upgrade and clean activities"

Tags: apt, 19.10

For a while now I've had a problem where my system spontaneously and irrecoverably freezes. I'm currently on Kubuntu 19.10 but similar freezes have happened on other distributions I've tried as well. I think I've tracked down the section of /var/log/syslog that was written when the system went down:

```
Apr 29 17:43:03 strangelove org.freedesktop.FileManager1[1150]: Gwenview can only apply color profile on RGB32 or ARGB32 images
Apr 29 17:48:51 strangelove systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
Apr 29 17:49:14 strangelove systemd-resolved[653]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Apr 29 17:50:10 strangelove kernel: [ 2843.988842] kvm: disabled by bios
Apr 29 17:50:10 strangelove kernel: [ 2844.022360] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC disabled.
Apr 29 17:50:10 strangelove kernel: [ 2844.022361] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
Apr 29 17:50:10 strangelove kernel: [ 2844.022361]  Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
Apr 29 17:50:10 strangelove kernel: [ 2844.022361]  (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
Apr 29 17:49:14 strangelove systemd-resolved[653]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Apr 29 17:50:11 strangelove systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Succeeded.
Apr 29 17:50:11 strangelove systemd[1]: Stopped Load Kernel Modules.
Apr 29 17:50:11 strangelove systemd[1]: Stopping Load Kernel Modules...
Apr 29 17:50:11 strangelove systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
Apr 29 17:50:11 strangelove systemd[1]: Started Load Kernel Modules.
```

The first line relates to Gwenview, and I include it because it's the last message that appears to pertain to what I was actually doing at the time. The next line shows the "Daily apt upgrade and clean" task activating, and the system freezes a few seconds later. My forced reboot appears to begin around 17:50:11.

Any suggestions of things to look for or try? I've never tried to diagnose something of this sort before so I'm not sure what the procedure is.